# Why CodedUI test runs in one browser and does not in another with the same version

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a few automated UI tests implemented with CodedUI. I have a virtual machine where the tests are run by Test Manager (via test controller and test agent). The benefits of this set up is that I can do other work while the tests are run. If I use my desktop to run the tests.

Recently, these tests are failing. The test is not able to step over from a input field to input password field. So, every test fail due to the tests can't log in to the system under test.

When I run these tests on my desktop then the tests are run without any issue.

Since the tests have been failing there were no updates on either system. Only, restarts.

Both system is Windows 7. Both has the same IE10 version. I requested a new virtual machine and the issue is the same. Tests are failing.

I'm in the situation where I can't decide which way of working is the proper. I want my tests running on the virtual env.

Have anybody experienced like this? Do you know any method to identify what could be the problem?

Another part of the situation is that, if I set up the tests to run on Chrome, then they are running, but it seems CodedUI doesn't like working together with other browsers than IE. I got some "method is not implemented" exceptions. I feel this would be another hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my problem is really simple, however annoying and this is not the first I'm looking for when I experience issue. The browsers I use for test have different Browser Mode and Document Mode settings.

That one where the tests failed had "Browser Mode: IE 10 Compatibility Mode" and "Document Mode: IE 7 Standards".

The another one where the tests have passed had "Browser Mode: IE 10" and "Document Mode: quirks".

I modified the browser set up values and the tests are running properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Coded UI only works with IE, [unless you use Selenium components.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx)

If you can, add the error the test gives after failing. 
In any case make sure your test machine has access to the system you're logging into. To run a Coded UI test on a remote machine you also need to have a user logged in.

Comment: I run my tests using IE and the problem is that there are IE browsers with exactly the same version and the test fails on one and it doesn't fail on another one.

However, I'm going to extend my description with the error and it's nature.